# Voting in TF2 opens an optimisation menu instead. How can I change this?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'll be brief about this. Whenever a vote kick or vote change map comes out I press the voting keys (<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> I believe) so I press them, and it gives me an optimization menu.

How can I change this?

Comment: Side note: Are you using a custom HUD?  I'm using the default HUD and it properly accepts the vote buttons while a vote is running rather than bringing up the Contract HUD when I hit F2.

Comment: @Chicks Nope, im using stock guis.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I think it ended up being because there was something else bound to that key. I changed the voting keys to something else like <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd>. You can change the voting binds by opening up the [console](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3041-SHZN-9384) and typing the following:

```
bind "F7" "vote option1" 
bind "F8" "vote option2"
```

Comment: Thanks i believe this will work, since my other keys are binded. Oh, btw im pretty sure im using a Windows 8.1 Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Thebloodybackstabber No worries. If this solved the problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the green check mark below the voting buttons on the left :)

Answer (score 1):

This might also have something to do with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key occasionally being stuck. Depending on your device, there are different ways to get it unstuck, but a good starting point would be to restart your computer and see if it works then.